# Adobe analytics not getting repeat visits and only showing new visits

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

We have implemented adobe dashboard in our application which is Live and been used by quite a few Users
Adobe dashboard statistics shows we are not getting repeat visits instead it is only showing as new visits.

When looking at the cookies (post accepting the cookies banner message but within the same visit) there is a cookie called 's_vi' this goes away when we close the page and reopen it - leaving just our application cookies.

Working URL : .local

Not Working URL: .[mycompany].uk

This is working as expected on our local machine and only if we use the development scripts.
When we start using staging or live environments, the cookies are not restored.

Comment: Not a whole lot can help without seeing the page in question, but in general, pretty sure this is not something Adobe Analytics library is doing (or does in general). This sounds like some configuration issue with your cookie consent script.

Comment: Alternatively, possible your site framework might be doing something. For example, I've seen site frameworks configured to rewrite cookies to https only flag (making them only server-side readable) which would prevent AA lib (client-side / javascript) from reading them.

Comment: Some how the cookies are getting deleted, seems configuration issue.